# Error when trying to execute function on mainnet UniswapV2Router: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ether, ethers.js, hardhat

Hi i encountering this error when i want to execute smart contract onFlashLoan function: Error:

```
Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (reason="execution reverted: UniswapV2Router: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT", method="estimateGas", transaction={"from":"0xA20f9C4905Ec7219b2Afe3B1ba95B4E708a48141","to":"0x026b77a9aC8815C85B75d275103F8261BEe2Eb73","data":"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","accessList":null}, error={"reason":"processing response error","code":"SERVER_ERROR","body":"{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":453,\"error\":{\"code\":3,\"message\":\"execution reverted: UniswapV2Router: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT\",\"data\":\"0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002b556e69737761705632526f757465723a20494e53554646494349454e545f4f55545055545f414d4f554e54000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\"}}","error":{"code":3,"data":"0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002b556e69737761705632526f757465723a20494e53554646494349454e545f4f55545055545f414d4f554e54000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"},"requestBody":"{\"method\":\"eth_estimateGas\",\"params\":[{\"from\":\"0xa20f9c4905ec7219b2afe3b1ba95b4e708a48141\",\"to\":\"0x026b77a9ac8815c85b75d275103f8261bee2eb73\",\"data\":\"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\"}],\"id\":453,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\"}","requestMethod":"POST","url":"https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/API"}, code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT, version=providers/5.7.2)
    at Logger.makeError (E:\SandwitchV1\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:269:28)
    at Logger.throwError (E:\SandwitchV1\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:281:20)
    at checkError (E:\SandwitchV1\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\src.ts\json-rpc-provider.ts:78:20)     
    at JsonRpcProvider.<anonymous> (E:\SandwitchV1\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\src.ts\json-rpc-provider.ts:642:20)
    at step (E:\SandwitchV1\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\json-rpc-provider.js:48:23)
    at Object.throw (E:\SandwitchV1\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\json-rpc-provider.js:29:53)      
    at rejected (E:\SandwitchV1\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\json-rpc-provider.js:21:65)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  reason: 'execution reverted: UniswapV2Router: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT',
  code: 'UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT',
  method: 'estimateGas',
  transaction: {
    from: '0xA20f9C4905Ec7219b2Afe3B1ba95B4E708a48141',
    to: '0x026b77a9aC8815C85B75d275103F8261BEe2Eb73',
    data: '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',
    accessList: null
  },
  error: Error: processing response error (body="{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":453,\"error\":{\"code\":3,\"message\":\"execution reverted: UniswapV2Router: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT\",\"data\":\"0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002b556e69737761705632526f757465723a20494e53554646494349454e545f4f55545055545f414d4f554e54000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\"}}", error={"code":3,"data":"0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002b556e69737761705632526f757465723a20494e53554646494349454e545f4f55545055545f414d4f554e54000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"}, requestBody="{\"method\":\"eth_estimateGas\",\"params\":[{\"from\":\"0xa20f9c4905ec7219b2afe3b1ba95b4e708a48141\",\"to\":\"0x026b77a9ac8815c85b75d275103f8261bee2eb73\",\"data\":\"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\"}],\"id\":453,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\"}", requestMethod="POST", url="https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/VfGkLG582KZD2xh8nCf8_rAzcjHR88eW", code=SERVER_ERROR, version=web/5.7.1)
      at Logger.makeError (E:\SandwitchV1\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:269:28)
      at Logger.throwError (E:\SandwitchV1\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:281:20)
      at E:\SandwitchV1\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\src.ts\index.ts:341:28
      at step (E:\SandwitchV1\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:33:23)
      at Object.next (E:\SandwitchV1\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:14:53)
      at fulfilled (E:\SandwitchV1\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:5:58)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
    reason: 'processing response error',
    code: 'SERVER_ERROR',
    body: '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":453,"error":{"code":3,"message":"execution reverted: UniswapV2Router: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT","data":"0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002b556e69737761705632526f757465723a20494e53554646494349454e545f4f55545055545f414d4f554e54000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"}}',
    error: Error: execution reverted: UniswapV2Router: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT
        at getResult (E:\SandwitchV1\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\src.ts\json-rpc-provider.ts:142:28) 
        at processJsonFunc (E:\SandwitchV1\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\src.ts\index.ts:383:22)
        at E:\SandwitchV1\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\src.ts\index.ts:320:42
        at step (E:\SandwitchV1\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:33:23)
        at Object.next (E:\SandwitchV1\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:14:53)
        at fulfilled (E:\SandwitchV1\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:5:58)
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
      code: 3,
      data: '0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002b556e69737761705632526f757465723a20494e53554646494349454e545f4f555o":"0x026b77a9ac8815c85b75d275103f8261bee2eb73","data":"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"}],"id":453,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}',
    requestMethod: 'POST',
    url: 'https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/API'
  }
}
```

Smart Contract code :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/ReentrancyGuard.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Context.sol";
import "@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";

interface IERC3156FlashBorrower {
    function onFlashLoan(
        address initiator,
        address token,
        uint256 amount,
        uint256 fee,
        bytes calldata data
    ) external returns (bytes32);
}

contract FlashBorrower2 is Context, ReentrancyGuard, IERC3156FlashBorrower {
    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;

    address private owner;
    address USDC = 0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48;
    uint256 public constant MAX_INT = type(uint256).max;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier OnlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function onFlashLoan(
        address initiator,
        address token,
        uint256 amount,
        uint256 fee,
        bytes calldata data
    ) external override nonReentrant returns (bytes32) {
        IERC20(token).approve(msg.sender, MAX_INT);
        uint256 amountOutExpected;
        uint256 amountOutExpected2;
        (amountOutExpected, amountOutExpected2) = abi.decode(
            data,
            (uint256, uint256)
        );
        address UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS = 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D;
        address SUSHISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS = 0xd9e1cE17f2641f24aE83637ab66a2cca9C378B9F;

        IUniswapV2Router02 uniswapRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(
            UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS
        );
        IUniswapV2Router02 sushiSwapRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(
            SUSHISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS
        );

        address[] memory path2 = new address[](2);
        path2[0] = token;
        path2[1] = USDC;

        sushiSwapRouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(
            amount,
            amountOutExpected,
            path2,
            address(this),
            block.timestamp
        );

        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = USDC;
        path[1] = token;

        uniswapRouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(
            IERC20(USDC).balanceOf(address(this)),
            amountOutExpected2,
            path,
            address(this),
            block.timestamp
        );

        return keccak256("ERC3156FlashBorrower.onFlashLoan");
    }

    function withdrawWETH(address WETH) external OnlyOwner {
        require(
            IERC20(WETH).balanceOf(address(this)) > 0,
            "No funds to withdraw"
        );
        IERC20(WETH).transfer(owner, IERC20(WETH).balanceOf(address(this)));
    }
}
```

Function which executes function

```
let amountETH = ethers.utils.parseUnits("500", "ether");
const conadd= "contract address"
const token = "0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2";
   const feeData = await provider.getFeeData();
    const gasPrice = await feeData.gasPrice;
    let gasPriceGwei = await ethers.utils.formatUnits(gasPrice, "gwei");
    let newGasPriceGwei = parseFloat(gasPriceGwei) + 6;
    let newGasPriceGwei2 = newGasPriceGwei.toFixed(6);

    let newGasPriceWei = ethers.utils.parseUnits(
      newGasPriceGwei2.toString(),
      "gwei"
    );

      let formattedEX1S = ethers.utils.parseUnits(EX1S.toString(), "ether");
      let formattedEX2S = ethers.utils.parseUnits(EX2S.toString(), "ether");
      let dataF = ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.encode(
        ["uint256", "uint256"],
        [formattedEX1S, formattedEX2S]
      );

      const gasEstimateF = await contract.estimateGas.onFlashLoan(
        conadd,
        token,
        amountETH,
        0,
        dataF
      );

      const gasEstimateWithBuffer = gasEstimateF.mul(120).div(100);
      console.log("estimated gas with buffer:" + gasEstimateWithBuffer);

      const tx = await contract.onFlashLoan(
        conadd,
        token,
        amountETH,
        0,
        dataF,
        {
          gasLimit: gasEstimateWithBuffer,
          gasPrice: newGasPriceWei,
        }
      );
```

I think the expected amount may cause issues but i am not sure here is expected amount code

```
const slippageTolerance = 0.0004;
  const EX1S = sushiPrice * amount * (1 - slippageTolerance) - amount * 0.003;
    const EX2S =
      EX1S / (uniswapPrice * (1 + slippageTolerance)) -
      (EX1S / (uniswapPrice * (1 + slippageTolerance))) * 0.003;
```